# Sum of quantity based on name EXCEL VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to calculate the total qty for a specific name e.g 'test' based on Incoming and Outgoing, the formula is `=(SUMIF((B2:B6),"test",C2:C6))`, however I'm not exactly sure how i can do it in vba excel. Can anyone please help me?

```
A       B   C                       D
NAME    QTY DATE                    TYPE
test    1   16/2/2017 5:33:51 PM    Incoming
test    1   16/2/2017 6:16:11 PM    Incoming
rice    4   16/2/2017 6:16:23 PM    Incoming
test    -1  16/2/2017 6:16:40 PM    Outgoing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
Sub GetSum()
    Dim rng As Range, sum_range As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'update for your sheet name
        Set rng = .Range("A2:A6")
        Set sum_range = .Range("B2:B6")
        .Range("F2").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(rng, "test", sum_range) 'change F2 to your output cell
    End With
End Sub
```

**Update**

I edited the range addresses to match your description: "...calculate the total qty for a specific name".

Answer (score 0):

the exact translation would be

```
   someRange.Value=WorksheetFunction.SUMIF(range("B2:B6"),"test",range("C2:C6"))
```

but I guess you're actually after

```
   someRange.Value=WorksheetFunction.SUMIF(range("A2:A6"),"test",range("C2:C6"))
```

since in your example "test" is in column A

in any case set the *1st* range as the one where to search for "test" and the *2nd* range as the one where to sum up in

Comment: I thought the same, but came to the conclusion it was actually meant to be A and B which probably got shifted one by relative refs. Edit: OP actually says they are calculating *quantity*

Comment: @CallumDA, the first range is where "test" is supposed to be found, not the calculation range

Comment: This is what I mean: `=SUMIF(A2:A6,"test",B2:B6)` which calculates quantity given "test"

Comment: I see: my primary concern was the "A2:A6" range, as opposite to the `(B2:B6)` part of OP's formula. In any case, as it often happens, it proves fast to ask and get the answer home while a little harder to give feedback!